# AWS Ruby-sdk: How can I create a IAM user with auto generated password

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am using AWS Ruby-sdk to create a IAM user by only specifying a username. The password should be auto-generated. I couldn't find anything related to this in the API docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/index.html)

Comment: You should generate it yourself

Comment: @Max so I should have my own routine to generate passwords? In the AWS console there is an option to "Assign auto generated password" for the new IAM user. I assume that there must be something in the API to do this programmatically.

Comment: I don't think that's part of the API, I think it is a service provided by the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IAM does not have an auto-generate password feature in their API. Their web console is providing this functionality on behalf of its users. To create a password for a user using the AWS SDK for Ruby, you can do the following:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

iam = Aws::IAM::Resource.new
user = iam.create_user(user_name: 'name')
user.create_login_profile(password: 'randompassword', password_reset_required: false)
```

You can of course use any method your prefer to randomize a password. A simple mechanism for this would be to use SecureRandom from Ruby's standard library:

```
# creates a random password of 10 hex characters (length is 2x the given n)
require 'securerandom'
password = SecureRandom.hex(5) 
#=> "764d9308a3"
```